# Is there a way to make uneven div in Zurb foundation 5?

Tags: zurb-foundation-5

I know the usage of block-grid in Foundation.. Now I wan to make uneven div 's for example, Two rows and  three columns. The columns on the left has one div in each row. Same goes for  column on the right.The column in the middle should have only one div expanding to the full length of the two rows. Is it possible to do this in Foundation 5?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding the issue correctly - are you seeking to have matching height columns regardless of content?

If so, Foundation's equalizer plugin will handle this. Hope this helps :)

[Equalizer plugin for Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/equalizer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Possible you can solve your issue by using [nested grids](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-4 columns">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">Nested</div>
        <div class="small-12 columns">Nested</div>
    </div>    
  </div>
  <div class="small-4 columns" style="background-color:green;color:white;">Middle<br>next row</div>
  <div class="small-4 columns">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">Nested</div>
        <div class="small-12 columns">Nested</div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```